# TokBox/OpenTok/Vonage Streaming mixing Howto

Tags: opentok, tokbox

Is it possible to combine multiple audio stream with the TokBox/Vonage API?

I have two or three WebRTC streams sending to OpenTok cloud and would like to have the streams combined and have the listeners to receive the combined stream.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

It sounds like you're looking for our [Live Streaming Broadcasts](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/broadcast/live-streaming/) feature. This type of broadcast lets you share an HTTP live streaming (HLS) stream or an RTMP stream with a large numbers of viewers. The HLS or RTMP stream is a single video composed of the individual streams published to the OpenTok session.